# How i can parse string to Component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I  have  a string like this:

```
const com = '<div><ComponentName data="abc" ></div>';
```

How I can parse this string as a component in `React js`.
I want react not to use it as a string.
Thanks

Comment: Please reword and proofread your question - it is hard to understand what exactly you want to do. Do you want to be able to define `'<div><ComponentName data="abc" ></div>'` as a React Component?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to output html string as real html?

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      com: '<div><ComponentName data="abc" ></div>'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.com}} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```